# Django Nginx static file caching on browser

Tags: django, caching, nginx, configuration, django-staticfiles

I am trying to configure Nginx to leverage on static file caching on browser. My configuration file is as following

```
server {

listen   80;
server_name localhost;

client_max_body_size 4G;

access_log /home/user/webapps/app_env/logs/nginx-access.log;
error_log /home/user/webapps/app_env/logs/nginx-error.log;

location /static/ {
    alias   /home/user/webapps/app_env/static/;
}

location /media/ {
    alias   /home/user/webapps/app_env/media/;
    }
...
}
```

When I add in the following caching configuration, the server fails to load static files and I am not able to restart my Nginx.

```
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires 365d;
}
```

The nginx-error log shows open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/media/cover_photos/292f109e-17ef-4d23-b0b5-bddc80708d19_t‌​humbnail.jpeg" failed (2: No such file or directory)

I have done quite some research online but cannot solve this problem.

Can anyone help me or just give me some suggestions on implementing static file caching in Nginx? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Nginx Browser Caching Configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508683/django-nginx-browser-caching-configuration)

Answer (score 3):

For caching static files, I would recommend you to do this way

```
location /static/ {
  alias /home/ubuntu/app/staticfiles/;
  expires 365d;
}
```

for "No such file or directory" errors do run

```
    ./manage.py collectstatic
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe run `./manage.py collectstatic` ?

Comment: Hi @Steven Xie, do we need to collect statics after changing the nginx configuration?

Comment: Yes if you changed the static location of the Nginx Configuration. By default it will collect all the static files to that location. If you changed it, better run it again.