# How to load site-wide static files in Django only once?

Tags: javascript, django, html, templates

I have multiple web pages which extend a base template, `base.html`.

Within `base.html` I load multiple JavaScript files (some are retrieved from the static directory, some are retrieved from a CDN):

`<script src="/path/to/file.js"></script>`

`<script src="cdn-website.com/path/to/file.js"></script>`

It appears that every time I click a link to a page that extends `base.html` the JavaScript files have to be requested again, which takes 1-2 seconds, so each page loads very slowly.

Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: No, because that's how web pages work.

Answer (score 0):

this is up to the server - when you use `python manage.py runserver` the behavior is intended, as you actually want all files to update properly. when you use a http server in front like nginx see here: [Django Nginx static file caching on browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497472/django-nginx-static-file-caching-on-browser)

nginx will tell the connected browser using HTTP Headers how long a particular file should be valid.